# I managed to break both my windows and my linux

Tags: error-handling

Now I have downloaded ubuntu today and have installed it on an empty partition, so it installs and I reboot my pc and am greeted by a message saying: "An operating system wasn't found. Try disconnecting any devices that don't contain an operating system." What do I do?

Comment: Try booting up a liveusb and check details of partition..

Answer (score 0):

I would try to boot the computer from a CD or a USB or a network, and see what do the partitions on your boot disk look like. Also check for disk integrity.

If the partitions and their contents appear as they should, then before proceeding further, we'll need answers to the following -
1) Which OS did you install first, Ubuntu or Windows ? 
2) Are you using UEFI ? 
3) Is secure boot ON/OFF ? 
4) Does your computer hardware support 64-bit ? Please share the entire specs if possible.

There are some known issues with dual-boot. You must follow the instructions at [How do I install Ubuntu alongside a pre-installed Windows with UEFI?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-alongside-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi/228069#228069) verbatim.